# A few cypress pipelines are always hanging, one cypress pipeline is always pass

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, gitlab, cypress

[image]In Gitlab there is a pipeline for UI testing (with three jobs written with cypress) that triggered after each push to project.
When a few pushes are done - is where the problem begins. The cypress pipelines are pending one after another and then the second pipeline is always hanging!
If I run one cypress pipeline no problem occurs, everything is fine.
What could be the reason?

```
Error: Cypress command timeout of '120000ms' exceeded.

Because this error occurred during a 'after each' hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: 'page_1'
```

This is the test that stuck, but I think that problem is related to gitlab runners. 
[image]

Comment: Could you share the spec code that is failing? Can we pinpoint where the `afterEach` is getting stuck?

Comment: @ZachBloomquist I added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I have a single job. GitLab gets stuck on test cases more than 50% of the time. Doesn't happen locally.